# heroku rake migration issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

I deployed to heroku: git push heroku master

then I try: heroku run rake db:migrate but it's show this issue:

```
error: src refspec logs does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:appname.git'
```

Please help me solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is stupid issue. I have the issue same you. I add alias on .bashrc file. alias heroku = 'git push heroku master'. this is reason when you run heroku always show this issue. remove this line. I'm sure it will solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You propably just need to commit first:

```
git commit -m "something"
```

Supposing you have added files for staging.

Comment: I commit & push all the change. Then: git push heroku master. it's Done. but I run migration. It's show this issue.

Comment: @khanh are you absolutely sure you've committed your changes? does `git log` show anything?

Comment: git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Answer (score 0):

Try deploy with `git push -f git@heroku.com:appname.git`